# Drupal 7 Views with BEF MAX_JOIN_SIZE Error

Tags: php, drupal-7, drupal-views

I am using Drupal 7 with Views and Better Exposed Filters so I can search for content nodes with taxonomy terms with checkboxes.  I only have about 25 pieces of content and 10 taxonomy term checkboxes.  When I check all the boxes, I am getting this error (which I can only see when in Views Preview):

SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1104 The SELECT would examine more than MAX_JOIN_SIZE rows; check your WHERE and use SET SQL_BIG_SELECTS=1 or SET MAX_JOIN_SIZE=# if the SELECT is okay

I found some advice that suggest using the following code to address this:

```
mysql_query("set sql_big_selects=1");
```

1. If this is the correct approach, where should this code be used?
2. Is this approach addressing a poorly written query and if so is there a solution?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

This issue came up on Drupal.org [here](http://drupal.org/node/361967). The gist is that `sql_big_selects` is set on your hosting to `0` for a reason, and so you should contact your admin/support to change this setting.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a solution; I am curious if it is the right one long term.

I grep-ed my entire site to find configuration files.  I found sites/default/settings.php.  It is reasonably good at describing how to use it.  There are security issues related to this file so it has default permissions set to exclude write permission entirely.  I used chmod 466 to set it for editing, then chmod 444 to set it back.  Don't forget to do this.

I found the un-commented code and added the last array element which sets SQL_BIG_SELECTS to 1.  Still wondering if the SQL code Better Exposed Filters generates is bad.  In any case, this fixed the error for now.

```
 $databases = array (
  'default' => 
  array (
    'default' => 
    array (
      'database' => 'name_one',
      'username' => 'name_two',
      'password' => 'not_telling_you',
      'host' => 'localhost',
      'port' => '',
      'driver' => 'mysql',
      'prefix' => '',
      'init_commands' => array(
        'big_selects' => 'SET SQL_BIG_SELECTS=1',
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
```

Comment: I am on a shared hosting environment.  I don't think I can change the overall DB parameters and can't take the instance up or down.